# Selection of an adequate architecture/design pattern for minimal working example

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have been tasked with developing a script that reads in some data in csv format and some statistical parameters in .ini format, performs some statistical tests on that data, and outputs a new csv file with new columns containing results of the statistical tests for each row. One important functionality is to be able to select "ranges" of rows from the data such that the user has control over which range of columns is getting used for the statistical tests.

I have dumbed down my program (which is much more complex) to the following toy example. The toy example makes no sense from a scientific point of view but I think it illustrates the functionality I am trying to achieve really well:

**The python code is as follows:**

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

config = ConfigObj('input_mwe.ini')
crit_slope = config.get('data').as_float('critical_slope')

start_col = config['subset']['start_col']
end_col = config['subset']['end_col']

t = list(range(int(start_col), int(end_col)+1))

intercept_list = []
slope_list = []
decision_list = []

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    y = list(row[start_col:end_col])
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(t, y)
    intercept_list.append(intercept)
    slope_list.append(slope)
    if slope<crit_slope:
        decision_list.append('accept')
    else:
        decision_list.append('reject')

df['intercept'] = intercept_list
df['slope'] = slope_list
df['decision'] = decision_list

df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

**input_mwe.ini has the following content:**

```
[data]
    critical_slope=0.2
[subset]
    start_col=3
    end_col=8
```

**input.csv has the following content**

```
Point_id,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,5,4,6,8,5,4,1,8,7,4
2,2,5,6,8,7,4,5,6,2,4
3,5,7,8,4,5,6,8,7,4,1
4,5,4,6,6,6,8,7,8,6,5
5,5,4,4,4,5,8,7,9,5,2
```

**The output is as follows**

```
,Point_id,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,intercept,slope,decision
0,1,5,4,6,8,5,4,1,8,7,4,5.3428571428571425,0.02857142857142857,accept
1,2,2,5,6,8,7,4,5,6,2,4,10.36190476190476,-0.9142857142857143,accept
2,3,5,7,8,4,5,6,8,7,4,1,4.40952380952381,0.22857142857142856,reject
3,4,5,4,6,6,6,8,7,8,6,5,6.0476190476190474,0.14285714285714282,accept
4,5,5,4,4,4,5,8,7,9,5,2,3.819047619047619,0.45714285714285713,reject
```

Now in reality I am performing many more statistical tests, and the decision to accept or reject is based on other parameters. Also the method to subset the columns from the input csv is slightly different.

However, this is irrelevant to my question. I would like to come up with a simple, well recognized and well tested design pattern which can allow me to replicate the above functionality using object oriented code. I have very little experience coming up with design patterns (although I have worked extensively with classes and objects before and know how to build them).

What would be a good, practical starting point to refactor the above into object-oriented code? What is a suitable design pattern to use? Can I use more than one design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I will go with dependency injection in order to separate everything and test each elements properly.

First, a small class to deal with configuration .

```py
from configobj import ConfigObj

class Config:

  def __init__(self, config_file : str):
      self.config = ConfigObj(config_file)
      self.crit_slope = config.get('data').as_float('critical_slope')
      self.start_col = int(config['subset']['start_col'])
      seld.end_col = int(config['subset']['end_col']) + 1
```

Then we want a class that return a part of the dataframe based on condition.

```py
import pandas as pd 

class DataSelector:

     def __init__(self, csv_file, config_file):
         self.df =  pd.read_csv(csv_file)
         self.config = Config(config_file)

     @property
     def by_column(self):
         return self.df.iloc[:,self.config.start_col:self.config.end_col].copy()

     @property 
     def get_x_y(self):
        for idx, row in self.by_column.iterrows():
            yield row.tolist(), range(self.config.start_col, self.config.end_col)
```

We want to have a statisctic class, for separeting analysis from config and data selection

```py
from scipy import stats

class MyStats:

    @staticmethod
     def critic_slope(x, y, critic):
         slope, intercept, *_ = stats.lineregress(x,y)
         if slope < critic:
             decision = "Accepted"
         else:
             decision = "Rejected"
         return slope, intercept, decision
```

Know we can create a bunch of functions to performs what we want .

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def analyse_critical(csv_file, ini_file, out_file):
    ds = DataSelector(csv_file, ini_file)
    df = df.by_column
    final_df = defaultdict(list)
    for x, y in ds.get_x_y:
        slope, intercept, decision = MyStats.critic_slope(x, y, ds.config.crit_slope)
        final_df["slope"].append(slope)
        final_df["intercept"].append(intercept)
        final_df["decision"].append(decision)
    for element in ["slope", "intercept", "decision"]:
        df[element] = final_df[element]
    df.to_csv(out_file)
    return df

def analyse_2(csv_file, ini_file, out_file):
    pass 

def analyse_3(csv_file, ini_file, out_file):
    pass
```